# Formulario dinámico

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema con este formulario, mi objetivo es que cuando el *select* tenga el valor **"Boton"** el *div* **"mostrar"** me muestre un *button* con el *value = "Ingresar"*, el cual esta oculto.

De momento no muestra nada, cuando el *select* tiene el *value* **"Boton"**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title> Acción onclick en js </title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).on('ready',function(){
  $('#mostrar').hide();
  $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
    var url = "datos.php";                                      
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {
         console.log(data); 
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>
<script>
  $('#boton').on('change', function(){
    var opcion = this.value;
    var input = "";
    switch(opcion){
      case "1":
      $('#mostrar').empty();
        input = '<input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />';
          $("#mostrar").append(input);
          $("#mostrar").show('slow');
    break;
  }}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mes" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>">
    <select id="boton">
      <option></option>  
      <option value="1">Boton</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mostrar"></div>

</form>
<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**datos.php:**

```
<?php  

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña  = $_POST['contrasena'];
$mes  = $_POST['mes'];
echo "tu usuario es: ".$usuario." contraseña es: ".$contraseña." y el mes es ".$mes;
```

Comment: Te genera algún error en la consola?

Comment: si, los siguientes: "SyntaxError: missing } after function body" y "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Comment: tu error es que te falta una llave al finalizar el segundo script, luego del break ban 2 llaves de cierre

Comment: ahi se arreglo el primer error pero sigue el segundo, y todavia no aparece el botom.

Comment: Edite la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respuesta Editada**

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mostrar').hide();  

  $('#boton').change(function(){
    var opcion = this.value;
    var input = "";

    switch(opcion){
      case "1":
      $('#mostrar').empty();
        input = '<input type="button" onclick="ingresar();" value="Ingresar" />';
          $("#mostrar").html(input);
          $("#mostrar").show('slow');
    break;
  }}); 
});

function ingresar(){
    console.log($("#formulario").serialize());
    var url = "datos.php";                                      
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {
         console.log(data); 
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title> Acción onclick en js </title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mes" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>">
    <select id="boton">
      <option></option>  
      <option value="1">Boton</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mostrar"></div>

</form>
<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias pero ahora se presento otro problema, el _div "resp"_ ahora no muestra los datos enviados en el ajax.

Comment: gracias amigo ahi se soluciono

Comment: De nada, dale un voto positvo

Comment: De momento no puedo por falta de reputacion.

Comment: Pero yo si hay te va mi voto a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Modifique tu `script` para que funcione:

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mostrar').hide();
  $('body').on('click','#btn-ingresar',function(){
    var url = "datos.php";                                      
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {
         console.log(data); 
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });

  $('#boton').change(function(){
    var opcion = this.value;
    var input = "";

    switch(opcion){
      case "1":
      $('#mostrar').empty();
        input = '<input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />';
          $("#mostrar").html(input);
          $("#mostrar").show('slow');
    break;
  }}); 
});
</script>
```

Como el botón es un elemento generado luego de cargar la página el `document ready` no reconoce ese cambio correspondiente.

Comment: gracias pero ahora se presento otro problema, el _div "resp"_ ahora no muestra los datos enviados en el ajax.

Comment: edite mi respuesta espero te sirva